# Need to recover data from RAID5 array with just two out of three working disks

Tags: 11.10, mdadm

When I go to bring up the array with mdadm, it complains I don't have enough components to start it.  This makes sense, since RAID5 normally takes a minimum of three disks.. but I don't want to buy another 2TB drive with prices what they are at the moment.. I just want to start it in degraded mode, get my data off of it, then use them as separate drives, copying the truly important stuff to both of them :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Great news.. I was able to answer my own question.

As much as the term scared me, I finally tried:
mdadm --assemble --force /dev/md0 /sda1 /sdd1

and I was rewarded with the message:
mdadm: /dev/md0 has been started with 2 drives (out of 3)

Hope this is useful to someone else.. in related news, the wikipedia article on [mdadm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mdadm) (as of 2011/12/11) actually is one of the better resources out there for troubleshooting RAID mishaps.